# MatDatePickerModule - no provide for dateAdapter

Tags: angular

i've this problem. on a div click i make a method call that is use to open a MatDialog, but it returns me an error :

MatDatepicker: No provider found for DateAdapter. You must import one of the following modules at your application root: MatNativeDateModule, MatMomentDateModule, or provide a custom implementation.

i've implemeted it in root (app.module.ts) and in every single component where i want to use it

but still returns me this error

what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you also declared your **dialog component** in your module.

```
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';    
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    'YOUR_COMPONENT',
    'YOUR_DIALOG_COMPONENT'  
  ]
  imports: [
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule 
  ]
})
```

You also need to add **MatDatepickerModule** and **MatNativeDateModule**  under providers if you are using Angular v7 or below.